# Exclude specific files and directory in ember test coverage (code climate 3.8)

Tags: ember.js, code-climate

> By default coverage includes all files under ember project. As i am
>   unable to coverage adapters/* , serializers/* etc in tests, how can i
>   exclude those files and directories from code climate coverage ?

Comment: Why are you unable to test those?

Comment: I have added the models and handled all the requests in config file of mirage. Yet am seeing coverage of 0.0 % in adapter & and some directory files.